# SQL Server 2016 R Services. Error in connection

Tags: r, sql-server-2016, microsoft-r

I've previously installed SQL Server 2016, and want to try its R Services.
I went through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tutorial and came to Step 2.5, where I had to test connection by this script:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',  
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',    
@input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'  
with result sets (([hello] int not null));  
go
```

Error is:

```
Msg 39021, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An external script error occurred: 
Unable to launch the runtime. ErrorCode 0x80070490: 1168(Element not found.).
```

I've googled, and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt653951%28SQL.130%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tutorial states that I have to uninstall and then install `RegisterRExt.exe`. I did that. Restarted computer and instance services. But error continues to come.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of SQL Server 2016 are you running (`SELECT @@version`)? And what happens when you try and start the SQL Launchpad service in services.msc?

Comment: @BobAlbright Launchpad works just fine, it is started. Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB3194716) - 13.0.1722.0 (X64)   Sep 26 2016 13:17:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I have no idea if this will help you but the next thing I'd do is try and upgrade (rebind) to R Server 9.0.1 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791781.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you're OK with the Microsoft Modern Software Lifecycle Support license. Rebinding will basically reconfigure Microsoft R Server and re-run RegisterRExt.

Comment: @BobAlbright, that didn't work either, it returns errors. In my opinion, the problem is that I have downloaded 2016 long time ago, and R<->SQL connection things changed. I just installed new instance, and that's working now.